Source generated logs are not being logged into Application Insights
I would like to have my source generated log messages appear in the Application Insights traces. Currently, standard ILogger logs are being sent to the Application Insights, so the connection seems to be working. I tried testing with the LogLevel set to Error. With both the standard LogError method and a custom LogErrorDetailed method. But only the standard method logs were sent to Application Insights.
The logging provider used is Serilog, with this configuration:
appsettings:
"Serilog": {
  "MinimumLevel": {
    "Default": "Information",
    "Override": {
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  }
}

relevant serilog configuration in code:
var telemetryConfiguration = TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault();
telemetryConfiguration.ConnectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("ApplicationInsights") ?? throw new
    InvalidOperationException("Application Insights connection string is missing!");
logger.WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(telemetryConfiguration, TelemetryConverter.Traces);

LogErrorDetailed implementation:
[LoggerMessage(LogLevel.Error, Message = "{message} - {sourceFilePath} in method: {methodName} line: {lineNumber}")]
public static partial void LogErrorDetailed(this ILogger logger,
    string message,
    Exception exception,
    [CallerMemberName] string methodName = "",
    [CallerLineNumber] int lineNumber = 0,
    [CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "");


Update the Serilog configuration in appsettings.json to check that error-level logs are captured - { "YourNamespace": "Error" }

@SureshChikkam Error-level logs are being captured, at least from the standard Ilogger.LogError method, but I want to have the logs from the LogErrorDetailed method visible in the application insights too.

In the above appsettings.json file, It is specified with a default level of Information. It overrides the Microsoft.AspNetCore logging level to Warning. This means that the application will log all messages of level Information and above (including Warning, Error, etc.) from all sources, but only Warning and above from Microsoft.AspNetCore sources.

In the below provided code, the logging levels were set directly in the Serilog configuration in the code itself, with a MinimumLevel.Information and MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning), which accomplishes the same goal but may not be as flexible for deployment changes as it’s hardcoded.

Program.cs:
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            // Configure Application Insights
            var telemetryConfiguration = TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault();
            telemetryConfiguration.ConnectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ApplicationInsights")
                ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Application Insights connection string is missing!");

            // Configure Serilog
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Information()
                .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .WriteTo.Console()
                .WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(telemetryConfiguration, TelemetryConverter.Traces)
                .CreateLogger();

            // Replace default logging with Serilog
            builder.Host.UseSerilog();

            // Add services to the container.
            builder.Services.AddControllers();

            // Add Swagger services
            builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
            builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

            var app = builder.Build();

            // Use middleware
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            // Use Swagger middleware
            if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
                {
                    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
                    c.RoutePrefix = "swagger"; // Set Swagger UI at the app's root
                });
            }

            app.MapControllers();

            app.Run();
        }
    }
}

appsettings.json:
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "ApplicationInsights": "InstrumentationKey= //provide the key"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  }
}


Here, I'm able to capture the custom log detail message that you can check below.
Exception log:

Trace log:

The key difference lies in how the logging level is configured, Here the setup I provided was hardcoded.

Are you using the log method that is provided in the question?

Yes, the logging method provided in the question, LogErrorDetailed, is used for logging detailed error information.

The solution provided in this answer does not work for me unfortunately.

can you provide in detail that why does not working for you.

Changing the logging level related configuration didn't help. I then tried using the log message delegates approach, to see if the problem is related to the source-generated logs, but the custom logs were not being sent to the Application Insights still. Lastly, I tried using the Serilog static logger instance, to see if Serilog itself might be causing trouble, but those logs were sent to Application insights, so the root cause remained unidentified. For the time being I will just use a wrapper around the standard logger interface and disable warnings related to the logger messages.

Once try the custom logs locally and then again try same with app insights.
